# cypress.io: Command namespacing, chaining

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have read [docs here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Dual-Commands), and this is close to what I need, but not quite.
I am looking to create a simple namespacing like:

`cy.entity.create(name)`

`cy.entity.edit(id, data)`

`cy.entity.delete(id)`

so that my UI tests had a direct API call fallback where needed.
Is it possible to write commands in namespaced format like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cy` is a Javascript object, so if your goal is simply to store functions in cy.entity, this will work:

```
cy.entity = {};
cy.entity.edit = (id, data) => {
    cy.log(`cy.entity.edit(${id}, ${data}) has been called`);
    // ...
}

// Then you can call cy.entity.edit() like this:
cy.entity.edit("test", "test");
```